# El nombre 'Process' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'System.Diagnostics'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy tratando de abrir un documento PDF desde una ruta especifica, este es el código que tengo

```
string pdfPath = @"mi_ruta\archivo.pdf";
if (File.Exists(pdfPath) && pdfPath.ToUpper().Contains(".PDF"))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfPath);
}
```

Pero en el **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfPath);** me marca un error en el Process, el error es:

> El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'Process' no existe en el
>   espacio de nombres 'System.Diagnostics' (¿falta una referencia de
>   ensamblado?)

Como podría solucionar este error?

Comment: Hola amigo te hace falta agregar la librería del process using System.Diagnostics; ponlo en la parte de arriba de tu codigo

Comment: Estas en un desarrollo web, cual es el sentido de abrir un pdf de esa forma? lo estarias abriendo en el servidor, NO en el cliente

Comment: @EdgarVazquez cabe resaltar que ya tengo el using System.Diagnostics declarado, pero aun así marca error

Comment: @LeandroTuttini claro, estoy en un desarrollo web, y trato de abrir el archivo desde un servidor, entonces cual seria la manera correcta de abrir un archivo PDF? me podrías ayudar?

Comment: la manera correcta es enviar el pdf al cliente mediante un download del archivo, eso de abrir un archivo no aplica en un entorno web, solo se puede descargar. Si el browser que se usa ademas reconoce el content type y lo abre embebido en el browser eso sera adicional, pero en principio envias el pdf para su descarga

Comment: @LeandroTuttini entonces lo que debo de usar para mi caso es un Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; ? para abrir el archivo pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo con algo como esto lo resolverías

```
           string FilePath = Server.MapPath("javascript1-sample.pdf");  
           WebClient User = new WebClient();  
            Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);  
            if (FileBuffer != null)  
            {  
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());  
                Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);  
            }
```

Fuente :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-open-pdf-files-in-web-brower-using-Asp-Net/